Access - Set Subreport Control Properties With VBA
I have placed three unlinked subreports in the Report Header of a main report. I want the records in each subreport to be listed in two equal-height columns (down, then across), so in the ReportHeader_Format event of the main report I calculate the height needed for each subreport. Then I try to set each subreport control to its desired height with this:
Me.Section(acHeader).Controls(strSubreport).Height = intControlHt 

(I've also tried it without "Section(acHeader)").
Not only does this not work in Print Preview, but Access stops responding until I end the task. What am I doing wrong?

Setting the CanGrow property of the section that holds the sub-report toYes should do it without explicitly setting the Height.

How can a report with records be "unbound"? See if any help in https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/need-equal-length-columns-help.304000/

@BobS: The CanGrow property of the Report Header of the main report has no effect on the height of the subreports. The CanGrow property of the subreports is set to "No" because otherwise the records will only show in one long first column before going to the second, and will even spill onto the next page if the main report is set to "Yes".

@June7: Sorry, I meant to say that the subreports are not linked to the main report. I'll change it in my post.

@June7: As for the suggestion in the link, I did think about adding separate subreports for each column, but I thought that seemed a bit clumsy.

Trying to replicate your situation. When I use a muti-column report as a subreport, I lose the columns, just one long column of data stretching multiple pages.

I have used listboxes on a report to appear as multiple columns. Seven listboxes - each RowSource pulls data for a day of current week. Amount of data never expected to extend more than one page. Listboxes don't grow/shrink. I sized listboxes almost full length of page. Otherwise, I would use 7 subreports.

@June7: Yes, I know this is an alternative. But my question was about how to set the height of the subreport control.

I know what you are trying and I cannot replicate your situation to even test code.

@June7: When I manually set the subreport control to a short enough height, the records in the subreport (or as many of them as will fit) will populate both columns. So I'm trying to set the control height with VBA. The reference to the control in my code works to GET the height, but not when I try to SET the height. I would assume I should be able to do this no matter what's actually in the subreport itself.
